# Automator AppleScript log doesn't work. What am I do wrong?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

Here is what I tried:

[image]

I've tried google it, but no success

Comment: the first line should read `on run {input, parameters}`. I'm surprised it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't help…

Comment: The result of the log statements would need to be put someplace, for example the Script Editor/Debugger have a log display.  The **Run AppleScript** action doesn't have that, it just has the document display.  `display dialog` can be used, but if you have a script gf any size it would probably be better to use Script Editor/Debugger to develop it.

Answer (score 1):

@red_menace is right. The "Run AppleScript" in Automator doesn't show the info of `log` syntax. It's "Log" just show the log of running workflow.

`display dialog <string_variable>` may help a little, but it can't support the object type variable.

So I also suggest you use **Script Editor**, which is native app in Mac, and `log` info will be supported in it.